# How to remove WebResource.axd from asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, dll, configuration, webresource.axd

In my navigation bar there is a WebResource.axd file embedded as an image in dll file.

The path of WebResource.axd is:
src="/WebResource.axd?d=9M-49D3Ji5lBmHrEjR6rfTaqFb3jthECoNLnrcsU7mH8Lyg1lbLMdX-IKhDVenhWhqwKA1hi4HeD25BX0MuFZhHzfKwVNnl7K1VrsirLiJU1&t=634394609458919508">

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? It will likely cause something to stop working.

Comment: There is an arrow image embedded in menu with site map data source which I do not need it. The arrow shows on the right which I want down ward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a better question to ask is "How do you disable the default menu arrow image with the System.Web.Ui.WebControls.Menu control?"

The answer to that is to set the properties: DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage and StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage properties.

For example:

```
<asp:Menu id="menu" runat="server" 
   DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" 
   StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">
```

That will remove the rendering of the default image.